# Exporting location coordinates as .csv file

Tags: google-maps, csv, google-earth, google-earth-engine

Is there a way to export the coordinates of regions that have been drawn on a map in google earth engine to a .csv file?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can:

1. Open up the [Google Earth Engine Code Editor](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/playground).
2. Zoom and pan the interactive map to your area of interest.
3. Use the point, line, or polygon [Geometry Tools](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/playground#geometry-tools) to draw regions on the map. By default this will create an object named `geometry`, which will be listed on a new Geometry Imports menu that will appear to the right of the Geometry Tools.

[image: Various geometry types drawn on the map]

4. In the Geometry Imports menu, click on the settings (gear) icon for the `geometry` layer. In the "Import as" dropdown menu, select FeatureCollection.
5. In the code editing section, add a [command for exporting a table](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting#exporting-tables-and-vector-data):

```js
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection:geometry,
  description:'export_my_regions',
  fileFormat:'csv'
});
```

6. Click the Run button to run the script. This will create a new task in the [Tasks tab](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/playground#tasks-tab) called "export_my_regions".
7. In the Tasks tab, click Run next to the "export_my_regions" task. This will display a task dialog box. Click the Run button to initiate the export task.
8. Wait for the task to complete. After it finishes, there will be a new CSV available at the destination you specified. This example wrote the file to Google Drive, but you can write to Google Cloud Storage as well.
9. Open the CSV file in Google Sheets, or download it to your local computer to use in other software packages.

[image: CSV content displayed in Google Sheets]

If you want to export multiple feature collections as a single file, you 
can merge the feature collections into a single collection using [ee.FeatureCollection.merge()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eefeaturecollectionmerge). The following code also adds metadata to each feature that can be used to track the source once the features are merged.

```
var merged = featurecollection1.map(function (f) {return f.set({'source': 'source #1'})})
      .merge(featurecollection2.map(function (f) {return f.set({'source': 'source #2'})}))
      .merge(featurecollection3.map(function (f) {return f.set({'source': 'source #3'})}));

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: merged,
  description:'merged_regions',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Comment: I have done this and it works but the all coordinates appear on just the first line instead of multiple lines like the image above. How do I make the coordinates appear one line at a time?

Comment: Check step #4 and verify that your variable (i.e. 'geometry') is set to be a FeatureCollection. If you already tried that, could you share a link to your script (i.e. use the "Get Link" button to get a URL for sharing your script) so that others can try to replicate your issue?

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/22ab15aed232d7a854dac08019f713fc

Comment: @MichaelSaneke I appended a paragraph showing how to deal with multiple feature collections.